# Sum of the fractional series: $\{1\cdot a\}+\{2\cdot a\}+\{3\cdot a\}+\cdots+\{n\cdot a\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractional-part

Here $\{x\}$ denotes the **fractional part of x.**
In the series $\{1\cdot a\}+\{2\cdot a\}+\{3\cdot a\}+\cdots+\{n\cdot a\}$, **$a$ is an irrational number.**
I need to calculate the **sum** of this series.

The constant $a$ can be $1.414\ldots$, or $e$ (Euler number), etc.
Also, the value of $n$ can be very large, say of the **order of $2^{10000}$.**
So I am guessing there are some properties or theorems which might help to calculate the above but I don't have the required knowledge of them at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) says these fractional parts are equidistributed on $[0,1]$, so in particular your sum is asymptotic to $n/2$.  It's possible that more details on the asymptotics might be found.
But if you're looking for a "closed form", I doubt that such a thing exists for any irrational $a$.

Comment: Are you a Putnam fellow?

Comment: Based on nothing, I would not be surprised if a closed form existed for $a = \phi$.

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra Yes, that was me in 1971.

Comment: By Erdos-Turan inequality and Koksma inequality, we have $n/2+ O(n^{1-\frac1{\mu-1}+\epsilon})$ where $\mu$ is the irrationality measure of $a$.